# menu working, but not with |bash command

Tags: bash, remote, menu

below is a script that displays a menu, when I run it like `./menu.sh` it works, but when I run it like this: `./menu.sh | bash`

I get a lot of commands not found.

The reason I want to run it with `| bash` is because it will be on an ftp server and I need to run it from different remote locations. so I just do a `curl -s` to the ftp and if i do not use the `| bash` I just `cat` a printout of the code

```
    #!/bin/bash

#$path=./


while :
do
    echo " "
    echo " "
    echo "===== MAIN - MENU ====="


    echo "1. Run old sanity script"
    echo "2. Asterisk"
    echo "3. Audio"
    echo "4. CoCo"
    echo "5. Database"
    echo "6. Mobile"
    echo "7. SSH"
    echo "8. Touch"
    echo "9. VDS"
    echo "10. Wireshark"


    echo -----------------------
    echo "q. Quit"
    echo "r. Reload"
    echo "======================="

    echo -n "Please enter your choice: "
    read opt;
    echo " "
    echo " "

case $opt in


    1)  curl -s sanity_check.sh | bash;;
    2)  exec ./menu/asterisk/menu.sh;;
    3)  exec ./menu/audio/menu.sh;;
    4)  exec ./menu/coco/menu.sh;;
    5)  exec ./menu/database/menu.sh;;
    6)  exec ./menu/mobile/menu.sh;;
    7)  exec ./menu/ssh/menu.sh;;
    8)  exec ./menu/touch/menu.sh;;
    9)  exec ./menu/vds/menu.sh;;
    10)  exec ./menu/wireshark/menu.sh;;


    q)  echo " "
            echo "Bye Bye";
                exit 1;;
    Q)  echo " "
            echo "Bye Bye";
                exit 1;;

    r)  exec ./menu.sh;;
    R)  exec ./menu.sh;;

    *)  echo "$opt is an invaild option.";
            echo "Press [enter] key to continue. . .";
                read enterKey;;
esac
done
```

it gives me the following errors:

```
bash: line 3: =====: command not found
bash: line 4: 1.: command not found
bash: line 5: 2.: command not found
bash: line 6: 3.: command not found
bash: line 7: 4.: command not found
bash: line 8: 5.: command not found
bash: line 9: 6.: command not found
bash: line 10: 7.: command not found
bash: line 11: 8.: command not found
bash: line 12: 9.: command not found
bash: line 13: 10.: command not found
bash: line 14: -----------------------: command not found
bash: line 15: q.: command not found
bash: line 16: r.: command not found
bash: line 17: =======================: command not found
```

but for me these are just the echo commands ..... or am I missing something

Answer (score 2):

When running this code, it will output a text menu.  What you are doing with `./menu.sh | bash` is that you are feeding the menu into `bash` for execution.  In other words, you say to `bash`, "please execute this menu".  `bash` does not know what any of the text in the menu means, so it throws errors.

However, this is not how you say you will use this script.  You intend to fetch it (the script, not its output) and have it execute:

```
curl -o- 'ftp://.../menu.sh' | bash
```

This would not execute the script on the left hand side of the pipeline, while your `./menu.sh | bash` does.  So what you are proposing would probably work.

---

Also note that it's a fair bit easier to do multi-line output with a here-document:

```
cat <<END_MENU
===== MAIN - MENU =====
1. Run old sanity script
2. Asterisk
3. Audio
4. CoCo
5. Database
6. Mobile
7. SSH
8. Touch
9. VDS
10. Wireshark
-----------------------
q. Quit
r. Reload
=======================
END_MENU
```

Also investigate the `select` statement in `bash`.  It displays menus for you and makes it easier to do user input (unless you want special formatting of the menu and options, obviously).

You can also do multiple patterns in `case` statements:

```
q|Q)  echo 'Bye!'
      exit ;;
```

or

```
[qQ]) echo 'Bye!'
      exit ;;
```

(an `exit` due to the user's request should probably not return a non-zero exit code, by the way)

Comment: thanks for the advice,

the curl -o- option does not fully work, i still get a few errors...



i am currently looking in to the select option, but again here, when i want to run it form the remote server using the | bash statement at the end i get errors.

Comment: @WingZero huh? What error do you get?

Comment: 'bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
bash: line 4: $'\r': command not found
bash: line 5: $'\r': command not found
bash: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'ash: line 35: `case $opt in'

Comment: @WingZero This is because your script is a DOS text file.  DOS text files has an extra carriage return character at the end of each line. Are you writing it on Windows?

Comment: Hi,maybe  it is easier to get the whole story:

I've been a system admin for around 15 years now, always worked in windows environments.

due to a job change one and a half years ago, i started working on linux systems.

i am running ubuntu 18.10 atm, that is where i wrote my scripts (in visual studio code)

i have a lot of scripts that i need to run on different systems that are in different locations.

Comment: So i thought it would be easier to put them all on an ftp server and write a simple menu that splits the scripts in categories for easier use.

so thats why i am asking these questions about the menu, because i cant get it to work.

maybe i am handling this the wrong way and maybe there is a much easier what to get what want/need.

for the moment i am the only one using these scripts, but in the near future a lot more people will be using these scripts...

Comment: @WingZero I would say that you are solving the underlying issue in an unorthodox and awkward way. You may want to ask a separate question about this.

Comment: Hi, thatnks for the advice I've created a genereal question for my issue:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489874/running-scripts-from-a-remote-location

Comment: I think my issue is that i still think in the windows way of thing "old habbits" ;)

Comment: I think there are indeed dos returns at the end of the scirpt, howver they appear after i upload my file to the ftp site using filezilla, i dont know if another program might be better to upload the file

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the output of the script to bash. don't you want to send the text of the script to bash to make bash execute it?

```
cat menu.sh | bash
```

Comment: hi, these scripts are on an ftp server. is there a way to cat with username and password?

Comment: so i am still having issues with the |bash command at the end, i cant jus do an echo ...

Comment: do you have an idea on how to do en echo command together with the bash command?